# Get list of month of current year but months before current month

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

How to get list of month of current year but the list should have only month before current month.

Like now it is march of 2013 then the list should contain Jan 2013 and Feb 2013. and when April starts then it should have jan,Feb, march.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
 var x = new[]
        {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", 
         "Apr", "May", "Jun", 
         "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", 
         "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"}.Take
         (DateTime.Today.Month-1);
```

or if you want a concrete list,

```
 var x = new[]
        {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", 
         "Apr", "May", "Jun", 
         "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", 
         "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"}.Take
         (DateTime.Today.Month-1).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.Today.Month - 1)
    .Select(m => new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, m, 1))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks!!! it does give the answer but i was trying to get the month in string form.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps:

```
var today = DateTime.Today;
var beforeMonths = Enumerable.Range(1, 12)
            .Where(i => i < today.Month)
            .Select(i => new DateTime(today.Year, i, 1))
            .ToList();
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/EzDlUu)

Comment: Thanks Tim for answer but i was trying for string form. But thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well other than the result for January returning an empty list (which may be what you want) you could use:

```
Enumerable.Range(1,DateTime.Today.Month - 1)
          .Select(i => new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year,i,1));
```

or if you want the string representations use

```
Enumerable.Range(1,DateTime.Today.Month - 1)
          .Select(i => new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year,i,1)
                           .ToString("MMM yyyy"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the month

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var months =
            Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.Now.Month-1).Select(
                p => new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, p, 1));

        foreach(var month in months)
            Console.WriteLine(month.ToString("MMM yyyy"));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the current month by

```
DateTime.Today.Month;
```

Which for march is 3.

Then you can just loop from 0 to DateTime.Today.Month incrementing the month.

```
List<DateTime> months = new List<DateTime>();

for (int i = 0; i < DateTime.Now.Month; ++i)
{
     months.Add(new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, i, 1));
}
```